# Rails: link_to - passing a subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, subdomain, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to create a link_to to a different subdomain.

This is what I came up with:

```
= link_to "Link to Subdomain", root_path(subdomain: "abc", param1: "value1", param2: "value2")
```

It is not working though. I get redirected to:

```
http://lvh.me:3000/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

**Note:** The as param passed `subdomain` is not being displayed in the url. *Neither as subdomain nor as parameter.*

Instead I want to get redirected to the following URL:

```
 http://abc.lvh.me:3000/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah... you are using `root_path` which by definition is a relative url (ie it does not contain the domain)... you probably want `root_url` which will fully specify the domain (and subdomain).

Comment: Thank you! Cannot believe I missed that :-)

Comment: :D it happens to all of us... way more often than we like to admit ;)